# AFnetworking Multipart data of image in base64 encoding format

Tags: ios, objective-c, base64, image-uploading, afnetworking-2

How can i send Base64 image encoded to the server using af networking. I have converted the image in to base 64 but the problem is in sending the image to the server. Iam new to ios so please help me in resolving this issue.

```
NSString *surl = @"https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            surl = [surl stringByAppendingString:userID];
            NSLog(@"%@", surl);

            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
            [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:surl]];
            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            [request setValue:@"multipart/form-data" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];




            NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];
            [postBody appendData:[base64 dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


            [request setHTTPBody:postBody];
            NSLog(@"postbody%@", postBody);
            AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]initWithRequest:request];

            operation.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

            [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                NSLog(@"JSON Successsss: %@", responseObject);


            } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                 NSLog(@"error: %@",error);
                NSHTTPURLResponse *response = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)operation.response;

                NSLog(@"statusCode: %ld", (long)response.statusCode);

                NSString* ErrorResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:(NSData *)error.userInfo[AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseDataErrorKey] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                NSLog(@"Error Response:%@",ErrorResponse);

            }];
            [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:operation];
        }
```

Comment: If you convert an `UIImage` to base64 it is `NSString` and you can send it in same way as you send parameters to server. Still you need to show your code to get help.

Comment: Hope this link will help you [Correct way to embed base64 in json payload with AFNetworking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11814133/correct-way-to-embed-base64-in-json-payload-with-afnetworking?answertab=active#tab-top)